# Resize image of CKEditor in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using this CKEditor `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.22.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>`. I am using below code to resize images.

```
var editorConfig = {
      height: '400px',
      filebrowserUploadMethod: "form",
      filebrowserUploadUrl: "main_blog_upload.php",
      defaultLanguage: "es",
      language: "es",
      image: {
        resizeUnit: 'px', 
        toolbar: ['resizeImage:50', 'resizeImage:75', 'resizeImage:original'],
        resizeOptions: [
          {
            name: 'resizeImage:original',
            value: null,
            icon: 'original'
          },
          {
            name: 'resizeImage:50',
            value: '50',
            icon: 'medium'
          },
          {
            name: 'resizeImage:75',
            value: '75',
            icon: 'large'
          }
        ]
      },
    };

    
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor', editorConfig);
```

But image resize is not working in Google Chrome.